# how to use spray json4s support to marshal json data as snake case

Tags: scala, spray, json4s

Scala case class fields are camelcased,

> but I want to produce json with snake case.

Is there anyway to do this ?

> The Json4sSupport trait seems have no way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JValue` has a [`snakizeKeys`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/MonadicJValue.scala#L341-L344) function.

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val json = """{
             |  "lowerCamelCase": 100,
             |  "UpperCamelCase": 100,
             |  "snake_case": 100,
             |  "dashed-case": 100,
             |  "using spaces": 100
             |}""".stripMargin

val ast = parse(json)

println(pretty(ast.snakizeKeys))

//  {
//    "lower_camel_case" : 100,
//    "upper_camel_case" : 100,
//    "snake_case" : 100,
//    "dashed_case" : 100,
//    "using_spaces" : 100
//  }
```

You probably want to hook the conversion in a post-processing step on the response and/or pre-processing of the request.

Comment: Shall I write a customer marshaller ?

Comment: That would work. You can build on the [existing one](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.2/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/Json4sJacksonSupport.scala).